# Создание папки и добавление в нее изображения GitHub

Tags: изображения, github, репозиторий

Мне нужно создать папку, в которой будет ещё 2 папки, а в каждой по изображению.
Т.е.

```
 Репозиторий-ветка-папка/папка-изображение
                        \папка-изображение
```

Помогите!

Comment: А в чём проблема-то? Открыть Проводник, создать да закоммитить как обычно

Answer (score 0):

Чисто от нечего делать пишу..

```
cd нужная папка
git branch 
Смотрим нужную ветку
git checkout нужная ветка 
mkdir Папка_с_фото_1 Папка_с_фото_2
Помещаем фотографии в нужные папки
git status 
Проверяем все ли окей 
git commit -am "пишим коммит"
Добавили, закомитили 
git push туда куда нам нужно
```